# Coallate logs by date/time, from seperate servers, with powershell

Tags: sorting, powershell, logging

I'd like to have a script that grabs the logs from a list of paths and sorts all the entries in the logs into one large consolidated log. I'm fairly new at programming and powershell, but I've got a start.  The log entries look like this:

2013-07-17 05:00:00,003 INFO  [com.mpi.mp.viewer.web.servlet.ViewerLogFlusher] Skipped sending the empty string to wmsiislo

What I'm thinking is that I need to somehow parse each line into a multidimensional array, and sort it.  The problem is, I can't get the hang of the [DateTime] method.  My very incomplerte code is below:

```
#Code to append all logs together

$Biglog = Get-Content C:\Temp\logs\server1.log 
foreach ($line in $Biglog){
#do something

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ls c:\temp\logs\*.log | gc | out-file c:\temp\log.txt
Import-Csv C:\temp\log.txt -Header "date","info" |Sort-Object date | export-csv c:\temp\sortedlogs.csv
```